# Javascript Module Pattern Help

Tags: javascript, module, design-patterns, javascript-framework

The problem I have is that there are a set of variable values / properties in one file and a library in another file. I have started refactoring the code but still need to keep variable values(dynamic) and library(static) differently.

I am using namespacing and overall want only one global namespace.

The problems I have at the moment:
1. How can I still keep one global namespace
2. What is the best way to read the values from one file and use it in the library present in another file.

e.g I came up with something like

```
//File ONE with values 
var main.dynamicvalues = (function(){ 
    var a = 10,
    b = 20,
    c = 30;
    return {
        a:a,
        b:b,
        c:c
    }
}());


//File TWO with core Library
var main.library = (function(){ 
    //Various Private functions that need to use a,b,c variables from above main.dynamicvalues namespace

    return {
        //Public functions again need to use a,b,c from above namespace.
    }
}());
```

Is there a way I can have a pattern so that I keep only one global namespace and can refer to variables directly without having to use maincode.values.a, maincode.values.b, maincode.values.c or something like this in maincode.library.functions

Thanks
Sparsh Gupta

Comment: try AMD. The commonJS asynchronous modules definition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This approach is a little better, but it's not exactly what you're looking for.

```
var main = {};

main.dynamicvalues = (function() {
 // same as before
})();


main.library = (function(dyn){   
        // use dyn.a, dyn.b etc

        return {

            // same in here
        }
    }(main.dynamicvalues));
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a new file (maybe name it something like "common.js") and put the values there.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/). This will let you do what you want with no global namespace at all (if you'd like to). In addition it will give you non-blocking script loading, easy way to handle dependencies and a build tool.

On the other hand, it can deprive you of the joy of investigating things for your own and better understanding of js architectural patterns.

Your code with RequireJs could have looked like this:

```
// File one with values, let's name it values.js
define([], function() {
    var a = 10,
        b = 20,
        c = 30;
    return {
        a: a,
        b: b,
        c: c
    }

})

// File two with library
define([
    // load values.js as a dependency
    'values'
    // what is returned in values.js can be passed as an argument to the callback
    ], function( values ) {
    values.a === 10 // true
})
```